# Does inheritance change the offset of a field obtained with the Unsafe class? Or depends on the specific virtual machine implementation?

Tags: java, jvm

When I tried to understand "Unsafe.objectFieldOffset", I am confused by the comments in the code.

```java
// Any given field will always have the same offset, and no two distinct fields of the same class will ever have the same offset.
```

Does this mean that I get the offset of a field in the abstract class, this field still has the same offset in the implementation class because they are the same field?

The following is sample code, just to illustrate the problem:

```java
public abstract class Parent {
    protected Object value;
}
```

```java
// Because the question is asked for any implementation class, only a simple example is given
public class Son extends Parent {
    public Son(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    Object useless_1;
    Object useless_2;
    Object useless_3;
    Object useless_4;
}
```

```java
public class ParentTool {
    protected static final long offset;
    private static final Unsafe unsafe;

    // Initialize static fields
    static {
        try {
            Field field = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            unsafe = (Unsafe) field.get(null);
            offset = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(Parent.class.getDeclaredField("value"));
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }

    // Hope this method can get and set the fields correctly
    protected static Object getAndSetValue(Parent parent, Object newValue) {
        return unsafe.getAndSetObject(parent, offset, newValue);
    }
}
```

The startup class used for testing is as follows

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Son son = new Son("hello");
        Object value;

        value = ParentTool.getAndSetValue(son, "world");
        System.out.println(value == "hello"); // true
        value = ParentTool.getAndSetValue(son, "test");
        System.out.println(value == "world"); // true
    }
}
```

The operation results are as expected

```
true
true
```

Does "getAndSetValue" always work for any class that inherits Parent?
Does this depend on the specific virtual machine implementation?

The JDK version I use is shown below

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.222.10.3
```

This question was raised out of curiosity about the Unsafe class. If this question is too broad or not suitable here, please let me know in the comments to improve or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Child classes typically share the structure of a parent class, possibly adding more fields after all parent fields. This is not specific to Java - the inheritance in other languages (e.g. C++) is implemented in a similar way. This makes possible to use a child class as an instance of a parent class efficiently without a dynamic type check.

Therefore, the offset of the field will remain the same in the parent class and in its all descendant classes. The JVM *is not* required to do so, but all reasonable implementations I'm aware of, follow this rule.

Strictly speaking, `Unsafe` class is already an implementation detail of the particular JVM, so all statements about `Unsafe` are VM-specific by definition.

Comment: The additional fields don’t have to be strictly after the parent’s fields. They may fill gaps caused by alignment, for example. That still wouldn’t change the parent’s field offsets.